# unable to add contacts to jitsi

Tags: ubuntu, sip, voip, jitsi

I have installed jitsi version 2.10.5550 for sip communication on my ubuntu 16.04 in my office laptop.

Whenever i try to add contact via the File -> Add contact or from the Call history screen, Right Click -> Add contact, after filling in the contact details the Add button is not enabled.

Is there anything that needs to be done to be able to add / save contacts in Jitsi.

[image: Jitsi Add Contact Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Jitsi, as I've been experiencing the same issue on Trisquel GNU/Linux for a long time. I've raised this on the [Jitsi users](http://lists.jitsi.org/pipermail/users/2017-November/013720.html) mailing list - they request you do this before raising a bug report directly.